# Using Index Value on document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

Why does the [0] before the semicolon of the constant declaration work?

```js
const myHeading = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
const myTextInput = document.getElementById("myTextInput");
const myP = document.getElementById("myP");

myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myHeading.style.color = myTextInput.value;
});
```

Comment: The function returns an array-like value.

Comment: Why you think it should not ? `document.getElementByTagName` gives you array like object and you can access index

Comment: we are here to help you make your code work not explain your code for your code.

Comment: yes i know but why is it placed right after document.getElementsByTagName("h1") @Pointy

Comment: @CodeManiac because its right after document.getElementsByTagName("h1") its a weird place for it.

Comment: @HeavensGate666 it's not weird in case you just want to get only first element, you write like this

Comment: @CodeManiac ok i think it just looks weird to me because im new to all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the [0] before the semicolon of the constant declaration
>   work?

Log the value of `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")`. You may see something like this

```
{
  "0": <h1> Here is a Header</h1>,
  "length": 1,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] }
}
```

which apparently represent an object & now iterate that object using `for..in` you will get the keys `0`, `length` ,`item` and so on, where `0` represent the dom element. In order to access a object property you can use square notation `[]` and pass the key name inside it. So `["0"]`. So basically `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]` is accessing the element with key name `0` form the collection. Hence `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]` works

```js
const myHeading = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

console.log(myHeading);
for (let keys in myHeading) {
  console.log(keys)
}

const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
const myTextInput = document.getElementById("myTextInput");
const myP = document.getElementById("myP");
myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myHeading[0].style.color = myTextInput.value;
});
```

```html
<h1> Here is a Header</h1>
<input type='text' id='myTextInput'>
<button type='button' id='myButton'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

It returns an array-like value (HTMLCollection I believe) and so to access the first one, you use array notation `[0]`. If you don't want to do that, use `querySelector` instead:

```
const myHeading = document.querySelector("h1");
```

The reason the `[0]` is placed after the call to `getElementsByTagName()` is because with functions returning values, you can think of it as replacing the call with the returned value - therefore, it goes after the call to get the first element. If you like, look at it like this:

```
const headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
const myHeading = headings[0];
```

Comment: I know what array notation is but why does it have to go right after document.getElementsByTagName("h1"). I think it is a weird place to be in

Comment: @HeavensGate666 what would be a less weird place? The return value from the function call is an array-like object, so putting array index stuff right after the function call makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Its return a collection of node. We need to access it via its index.